# VBA Excel - Export PDF file from Excel with second page

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

Just want to ask if how can I export a PDF file with vba? The thing is I do have a **10-F** and **10-B** sheet. The code below is working in the 10-F sheet. My problem is how can I export the data in the 10-B sheet together with the 10-F? The first page is the data in 10-F while the data in 10-B will be on the second page.

The range for the 10-B sheet is `"B10:AD92"`.

```
Sub Ver_PDF()

        'Create and assign variables
        Dim saveLocation As String
        Dim rng As Range
        lname = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HOME").Range("K12")
        fname = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HOME").Range("K13")
        Name = fname & " " & lname
        
        pdfile = "V-" & Name & ".pdf"
        
        saveLocation = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\V-PDF\" & pdfile
        Set rng = Sheets("10-F").Range("B9:AD89")
        
        Dim strFileExists As String

        strFileExists = Dir(saveLocation)
    
        If strFileExists <> "" Then
        
            Dim Ret
            '~~> Change this to the relevant file path and name
            Ret = IsFileOpen(saveLocation)
            
            If Ret = True Then
                MsgBox "Please close the PDF file before proceeding...", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error"
                Exit Sub
            End If
    
        End If
        
        rng.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        FileName:=saveLocation, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
        
End Sub
```

Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Before printing, add a new sheet say 10-print, copy and paste the 10-B and 10-F ranges to 10-print then export as pdf and delete 10-print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will do what you want. Change the worksheet names in the array as well as the destination path and file name.

```
Sub ExportAsPDF()

    Dim FolderPath  As String
    Dim FileName    As String
    
    FolderPath = "D:\Test PDFs\"            ' change to suit: end on back-slash
    FileName = "Test"                       ' change to suit
    On Error Resume Next
    MkDir FolderPath
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    Worksheets(Array("10-F", "10-B")).Select
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                                    FileName:=FolderPath & FileName & ".PDF", _
                                    OpenAfterPublish:=True, _
                                    IgnorePrintAreas:=False

    MsgBox "PDF was successfully created."
    Worksheets(1).Select
End Sub
```

Change `OpenAfterPublish` to *False* if you don't want to see the result right away.